# Showing page count with ReportLab

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm trying to add a simple "page x of y" to a report made with ReportLab.. I found [this old post](http://two.pairlist.net/pipermail/reportlab-users/2002-May/000020.html) about it, but maybe six years later something more straightforward has emerged? ^^;
I found [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/546511/) too, but when I use it, the resulting PDF is missing the images..

Comment: I had this same issue. Here is the recipe from ActiveState utilizing NumberedCanvas that actually works:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576832/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to implement the NumberedCanvas approach from ActiveState.  It was very easy to do and did not change much of my existing code. All I had to do was add that NumberedCanvas class and add the canvasmaker attribute when building my doc.  I also changed the measurements of where the "x of y" was displayed:

```
self.doc.build(pdf)
```

became

```
self.doc.build(pdf, canvasmaker=NumberedCanvas)
```

**doc** is a BaseDocTemplate and **pdf** is my list of flowable elements.

Comment: I do have images displaying on the pdf without any problems. If you are having a problem with images, could you elaborate or start a new question?

Comment: It seems that this technique breaks intra-document links. When I used it, all the links from one part of the document to another part started navigating to part way down the first page, rather than going to their actual targets.

Answer (score 4):

use doc.multiBuild

and in the page header method (defined by "onLaterPages="):

```
global TOTALPAGES
if doc.page > TOTALPAGES:
    TOTALPAGES = doc.page
else:
    canvas.drawString(270 * mm, 5 * mm, "Seite %d/%d" % (doc.page,TOTALPAGES))
```

Comment: So how to force reportlab to make multiple passes? Using `doc.multiBuild()` alone is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Just digging up some code for you, we use this:

```
SimpleDocTemplate(...).build(self.story,
                             onFirstPage=self._on_page,
                             onLaterPages=self._on_page)
```

Now `self._on_page` is a method that gets called for each page like:

```
def _on_page(self, canvas, doc):
    # ... do any additional page formatting here for each page
    print doc.page
```

Comment: Yes but the tricky part is how to figure out the "of y" part :) That is, the total number of pages

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution for platypus, that is easier to understand (at least I think it is). You can manually do two builds. In the first build, you can store the total number of pages. In the second build, you already know it in advance. I think it is easier to use and understand, because it works with platypus level event handlers, instead of canvas level events.

```
import copy
import io

from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

Title = "Hello world"
pageinfo = "platypus example"

total_pages = 0


def on_page(canvas, doc: SimpleDocTemplate):
    global total_pages
    total_pages = max(total_pages, doc.page)
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setFont('Times-Roman', 9)
    canvas.drawString(inch, 0.75 * inch, "Page %d %s" % (doc.page, total_pages))
    canvas.restoreState()


Story = [Spacer(1, 2 * inch)]
style = styles["Normal"]
for i in range(100):
    bogustext = ("This is Paragraph number %s. " % i) * 20
    p = Paragraph(bogustext, style)
    Story.append(p)
    Story.append(Spacer(1, 0.2 * inch))

# You MUST use a deep copy of the story!
# https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2022-March/905728.html

# First pass
with io.BytesIO() as out:
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(out)
    doc.build(copy.deepcopy(Story), onFirstPage=on_page, onLaterPages=on_page)
# Second pass
with open("test.pdf", "wb+") as out:
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(out)
    doc.build(copy.deepcopy(Story), onFirstPage=on_page, onLaterPages=on_page)
```

You just need to make sure that you always render a deep copy of your original story. Otherwise it won't work. (You will either get an empty page as the output, or a render error telling that a Flowable doesn't fit in the frame.)