# Pagenumber format in rml reports in Openerp6.0

Tags: report, odoo, rml

In rml reports how can i change the current page number format from page:1 ,page:2 etc to something different. For eg:

page:1/2 in the first page and

page:2/2 in the second page...

how can i do this ? i am using openerp6.0
currently i use the following code in the company page in the openerp interface to get the page number.

```
<drawCentredString x="18.5cm" y="1.5cm"> Page: <pageNumber/></drawCentredString>
```

Comment: Sounds like it might be related to this old [reportlab question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/637800/4794).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my problem got solved just applied the below patch.

```
# HG changeset patch
# Parent 3fda5d5bbae001d42c56b5281e56fb2be0c8aa58
[FIX] use real page count for <pageCount/> flowable


diff --git a/bin/report/render/rml2pdf/trml2pdf.py b/bin/report/render/rml2pdf/trml2pdf.py
--- a/bin/report/render/rml2pdf/trml2pdf.py
+++ b/bin/report/render/rml2pdf/trml2pdf.py
@@ -118,7 +118,7 @@
 def draw(self):
     self.canv.beginForm("pageCount")
     self.canv.setFont("Helvetica", utils.unit_get(str(8)))
-        self.canv.drawString(0, 0, str(self.canv.getPageNumber()))
+        self.canv.drawString(0, 0, str(self.canv._pageCount))
     self.canv.endForm()

class PageReset(platypus.Flowable):
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for my OpenERP version 6.1.1

Changes was done in my Ubuntu server at:

```
/opt/openerp/server/openerp/report/render/rml2pdf/trml2pdf.py
```

Then restart openerp-server with following command:

```
sudo service openerp-server restart
```