# How to add total page count in PDF using reportlab

Tags: python, django, reportlab

```
   def analysis_report(request):

       response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
       response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=ANALYSIS_REPORT.pdf'
       buffer = StringIO()
       doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer)
       doc.sample_no = 12345
       document = []
       doc.build(document, onLaterPages=header_footer)

   def header_footer(canvas, doc):
       canvas.saveState()

       canvas.setFont("Times-Bold", 11)
       canvas.setFillColor(gray)
       canvas.setStrokeColor('#5B80B2')
       canvas.drawCentredString(310, 800, 'HEADER ONE GOES HERE')
       canvas.drawString(440, 780, 'Sample No: %s' %doc.sample_no)

       canvas.setFont('Times-Roman', 5)
       canvas.drawString(565, 4, "Page %d" % doc.page)
```

I above code i can bale to display the page number, but my question is how can i display "Page X of Y" where Y is page count and X is current page.

I followed this http://code.activestate.com/recipes/546511-page-x-of-y-with-reportlab/, but they explained using **canvasmaker**, where as i'm using **OnlaterPages** argument in build.

How can i achieve the above thing using canvasmaker or is there any solution using OnLaterPages ?

Comment: i think you have misunderstood the solution provided by the linked article. their way overrides the save function of a canvas. if you want to do it with Platypus (which I assume is what's going on since you reference `onlaterpages`) there's at least one other method mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637800/showing-page-count-with-reportlab

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the improved recipe http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576832/ which should work with images.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible workaround would be to use pyPDF (or any other pdf-lib with the funcionality) to read the total number of pages after `doc.build()` and then rebuild the story with the gathered information by exchanging the corresponding `Paragraph()`'s. This approach might be more hackish, but does the trick with no subclassing.

Example:

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader
[...]
story.append(Paragraph('temp paragraph. this will be exchanged with the total page number'))
post_story = story[:] #copy the story because build consumes it
doc.build(story) #build the pdf with name temp.pdf
temp_pdf = PdfFileReader(file("temp.pdf", "rb"))
total_pages = cert_temp.getNumPages()
post_story[-1] = Paragraph('total pages: ' + str(total_pages))
doc.build(post_story)
```