# Reportlab show page number and page count IF there is more than one page in a document

Tags: python, reportlab

Can anyone show an example how to show "page X from Y" on Reportlab's generated document if there is more than one page in a document (show nothing if there is only one page). I know some solutions, but they all mark pages regardless of total page number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was pretty easy. Asif's answer on SO [How to add total page count in PDF using reportlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233787/how-to-add-total-page-count-in-pdf-using-reportlab) helped me. The only thing that was needed was added 'if' clause in the save() function. Original code is here:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576832/

Tweeked save() function is:

```
def save(self):
    """add page info to each page (page x of y)"""
    num_pages = len(self._saved_page_states)
    for state in self._saved_page_states:
        self.dict.update(state)
        ### just a little tweek here
        if num_pages > 1:
            self.draw_page_number(num_pages)
        canvas.Canvas.showPage(self)
    canvas.Canvas.save(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

If using the report lab .prep markup language, the following works for displaying the current page number:

```
    <drawString x="475" y="30"Page <pageNumber/></drawString>
```