# Python ReportLab - Clickable TOC with X of Y page numbering

Tags: python-2.7, pdf-generation, reportlab

Using ReportLab 2.7, Python 2.7:

I can create a pdf with clickable bookmarks in the table of contents (toc), or I can create a pdf with "x of y" page numbering, but the bookmarkpage(key) appears to break when I try to do both.

Example code:

```
class MyDocTemplate(BaseDocTemplate):  
    def __init__(self, filename, **kw):
        self.allowSplitting = 0
        BaseDocTemplate.__init__(self, filename, **kw)
        template = PageTemplate('normal', [Frame(2.5*cm, 2.5*cm, 15*cm, 25*cm)]) #, id='F1'
        self.addPageTemplates(template)

def afterFlowable(self, flowable):
    if isinstance(flowable, Paragraph):
        txt = flowable.getPlainText()
        style = flowable.style.name
        if style == 'Heading1':
            key = 'h1-%s' % self.seq.nextf('heading1')
            self.canv.bookmarkPage(key)                
            self.notify('TOCEntry', (0, txt, self.page))
        elif style == 'Heading2':
            key = 'h2-%s' % self.seq.nextf('heading2')
            print key
            self.canv.bookmarkPage(key)
            self.notify('TOCEntry', (1, txt, self.page, key))

class NumberedCanvas(canvas.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._saved_page_states = []

    def showPage(self):
        self._saved_page_states.append(dict(self.__dict__))
        self._startPage()

    def save(self):
        """add page info to each page (page x of y)"""
        num_pages = len(self._saved_page_states)
        for state in self._saved_page_states:
            self.__dict__.update(state)
            self.draw_page_number(num_pages)
            canvas.Canvas.showPage(self)
        canvas.Canvas.save(self)

    def draw_page_number(self, page_count):
        self.setFont('Times-Bold',14)
        self.drawRightString(7.6*inch,.5*inch,
        "Page %d of %d" % (self._pageNumber, page_count))

    h1 = PS(name = 'Heading1',
    fontSize = 14,
    leading = 16)
    h2 = PS(name = 'Heading2',
    fontSize = 12,
    leading = 14,
    leftIndent = 25)

    #Build story.
    story = []
    toc = TableOfContents()

    #For conciseness, using the same styles for headings and TOC entries
    toc.levelStyles = [h1, h2]
    story.append(toc)
    story.append(PageBreak())
    story.append(Paragraph('First heading', h1))
    story.append(Paragraph('Text in first heading', PS('body')))
    story.append(Paragraph('First sub heading', h2))
    story.append(Paragraph('Text in first sub heading', PS('body')))
    story.append(PageBreak())
    story.append(Paragraph('Second sub heading', h2))
    story.append(Paragraph('Text in second sub heading', PS('body')))
    story.append(Paragraph('Last heading', h1))
    doc = MyDocTemplate("mypdf.pdf")
    doc.multiBuild(story, canvasmaker=NumberedCanvas)
```

Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you solve this problem? I encounter same thing with you.

Answer (score 1):

found this initially looking for a solution to no avail, however, figured something out which works for me and wish to share as follows:

With the starting point of the reportlab example as regards to creating a toc containing document -which I assume you used in the first place- proceed as follows.

Modify the template assignment in the init function by adding the options onPage and onPageEnd defining calls to functions for drawing a header and a footer onto the page as follows, guess you could do the same within one function only, however, I used two in order to separate the header/footer section in my usecase:

```
template = PageTemplate('normal', [Frame(2.5*cm, 2.5*cm, 15*cm, 25*cm, id='F1')],onPage=header,onPageEnd=footer)
```

add the named header/footer functions to your class as shown below with illustrating some options for clarification including the page number in the footer function to make sure the question is answered:

```
def header(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.drawImage('some_image.gif', 5,780, width=None,height=None,mask=None)
    canvas.setLineWidth(1)
    canvas.line(5,780,120,780)
    canvas.setFont('Times-Bold',16)
    canvas.drawString(108, 108, 'blah')
    canvas.restoreState()

def footer(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setFont('Times-Roman',9)
    canvas.drawImage('py.jpg', inch,inch, width=None,height=None,mask=None)
    canvas.drawString(inch, 0.75 * inch, "Page %d " % doc.page)
    canvas.restoreState()
```

Whatever you did with the added 'numbered canvas class' and why it breaks I don't know, but since your provided code reminds me strongly of the reportlab toc example I guess you can start with that, apply my suggested changes/additions and see how it goes.

That should do the trick, hope that helps!

Comment: Had the same problem nearly four years later. I missed the total_page count. However I found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637800/showing-page-count-with-reportlab

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on the overriden showPage method in your NumberedCanvas class, you must call the parent showPage method:

```
class NumberedCanvas(canvas.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._saved_page_states = []

    def showPage(self):
        super().showPage()
        self._saved_page_states.append(dict(self.__dict__))

    def save(self):
        """add page info to each page (page x of y)"""
        num_pages = len(self._saved_page_states)
        for state in self._saved_page_states:
            self.__dict__.update(state)
            self.draw_page_number(num_pages)
            canvas.Canvas.showPage(self)
        canvas.Canvas.save(self)

    def draw_page_number(self, page_count):
        self.setFont('Times-Bold',14)
        self.drawRightString(7.6*inch,.5*inch,
        "Page %d of %d" % (self._pageNumber, page_count))
```